# Conjecture of Kelly

Tags: graph-theory

In GTM 244,it writes:

**Two graphs G and H on the same vertex set V are called hypomorphic** if, for
all v ∈ V , their vertex-deleted subgraphs G − v and H − v are isomorphic.Does
this imply that G and H are themselves isomorphic? Not necessarily: the graphs
**2K1 and K2**, though not isomorphic, are clearly hypomorphic. However, these two
graphs **are the only known nonisomorphic pair of hypomorphic simple graphs**, and
**it was conjectured in 1941 by Kelly** (1942) (see also Ulam (1960)) that there are no other such pairs.

......

The union of simple graphs G and H is the graph G ∪ H
with vertex set V (G) ∪ V (H) and edge set E(G) ∪E(H).

---

**for G = (V,E) , H= (V,E')**

**if:**

H - v1 isomorphic G - v1

H - v2 isomorphic G - v2

H - v3 isomorphic G - v3

**then :**

(H-v1) ∪ (H-v2) ∪ (H-v3) = (H - v1v2) ∪ (H- v3) = H

(G-v1) ∪ (G-v2) ∪ (G-v3) = (G - v1v2) ∪ (G- v3) = G

According to :

**if :
A  isomorphic B,  C  isomorphic D,   then : A∪C isomorphic B∪D**   (I think so)

so (H-v1) ∪ (H-v2) ∪ (H-v3) isomorphic (G-v1) ∪ (G-v2) ∪ (G-v3).

**that means :  H isomorphic G**

**Is it right?**

---

**Edit:**
your answer is right ! Thank you, Mr. Wolfgang.

I want to discuss it in a little deeper:

(H-v1) ∪ (H-v2) = H - v1v2

(G-v1) ∪ (G-v2) = G - v1v2

**Suppose** we don't know wether v1v2 exist or not in H (G) in advance.

if v1v2 exist in H, but not exist in G, then H not isomorphic G.(**Case 0**)

for example **G = 2K1 , H = K2**

if we know in advance that v1v2 exist in H and G (**Case 1**), or v1v2 does not exist in H and G (**Case 2**),**then we can say H isomorphic G because they have a same adjacency matrix.**

since H -v3 isomorphic G - v3, so Case 0 is impossible, then it must be Case 1 or Case 2.

So H isomorphic G.

**Am I right ?**

this method can be used for adjacency matrix only.(to exchange the positions of two vertices in column only will make good phenomenon happen), but when applying it on incidence matrix for **Edge Reconstruction Conjecture with the support of  [ (H -e1) ∩ (H - e2) = H -e1 -e2] ,if failed.**(when exchanging the positions of two vertices, bad phenomenon happen). However in GTM 244,it mentioned that : Deduce from Exercise 2.7.13c that the **Edge Reconstruction Conjecture is true if the Reconstruction Conjecture is true.**

Answer (score 2):

No. Your statement " A isomorphic B, C isomorphic D, then : A∪C isomorphic B∪D (I think so)" is wrong. Take $A=B=K_{1,2}$, $C$ an edge of $A$, $D$ the edge which is not in $A$. Then $A\cup C=A$, but $B\cup D=K_3$.

Comment: I really appreciate your good answer. After thinking on it , I add some information to attck this conjeture again. In fact I lost confidence for myself.